# loading multiple libraries by using loadlibrary function

Tags: winapi, dll, msdn

I want to load the following libraries.

```
librariesmozcrt19.dll
nspr4.dll
plc4.dll
plds4.dll
mozsqlite3.dll
nssutil3.dll
softokn3.dll
nss3.dll
```

I know the single library can be loaded as

```
HMODULE hDLL=LoadLibrary(pDLLName);
```

But I'm not getting how load multiple libraries.

Comment: You could also consider using a load-time linking: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684184%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Call `LoadLibrary` for each library in turn. There is no "bulk load" API.